# Hazelcast Kubernetes Warning Unknown Protocol

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, openshift, hazelcast

I was using Zookeeper Hazelcast discovery but now i have changed it to Hazelcast-Kubernetes. It seems it is working fine but some times it prints warning message like :

```
2020-10-16 13:45:27.434  WARN 1 --- [.IO.thread-in-1] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection    : [10.131.6.73]:5701 [dev] [3.12.7] Connection[id=6, /10.131.6.73:5701->/10.131.6.1:58546, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=false, type=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=6, /10.131.6.73:5701->/10.131.6.1:58546, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=true, type=NONE], thread=hz.switch-data-analytics.IO.thread-in-1

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: OPT
             at com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.onRead(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:107)
             at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioInboundPipeline.process(NioInboundPipeline.java:135)
             at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKey(NioThread.java:369)
             at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKeys(NioThread.java:354)
             at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:280)
             at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.run(NioThread.java:235)
```

and

```
2020-10-16 13:45:27.438  WARN 1 --- [.IO.thread-in-2] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection    : [10.131.6.73]:5701 [dev] [3.12.7] Connection[id=7, /10.131.6.73:5701->/10.131.6.1:58548, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=false, type=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=7, /10.131.6.73:5701->/10.131.6.1:58548, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=true, type=NONE], thread=hz.switch-data-analytics.IO.thread-in-2

java.lang.IllegalStateException: TLS handshake header detected, but plain protocol header was expected.
             at com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.loadProtocol(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:125)
             at com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.onRead(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:87)
             at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioInboundPipeline.process(NioInboundPipeline.java:135)
             at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKey(NioThread.java:369)
             at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKeys(NioThread.java:354)
             at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:280)
             at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.run(NioThread.java:235)
```

I could not find any protocol usage like OPT or etc.

What should i do to clear this warning ?

Note :

I am using openshift and and my spring boot application use hazelcast distributed cache in 3 pods under one namespace.

Here is my setting :

```
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getAwsConfig().setEnabled(false);
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(false);
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getKubernetesConfig().setEnabled(true)
            .setProperty("service-name", applicationProperties.getHazelcast().getServiceName())
            .setProperty("namespace", applicationProperties.getPod().getNamespace());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar issue report in this [GH Issue](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes/issues/186). As described there, adding the following part might solve the issue:

```
- containerPort: 5701
```

In any case, it might be a bug of [hazelcast-kubernetes](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes). Feel free to add the "steps to reproduce" to the following [Hazelcast Kubernetes GH Issue](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes/issues/207).

Comment: Hi Rafal, than you i will try and come back with feedback